# Flushing CodeIgniter's unused or timeout cache

Tags: codeigniter, caching

How can find and deleter unused cache file in Codeigniter 2.x version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$this->cache->cache_info();` fetch all multidimensional array saved cached data and delete cache using this method `$this->cache->delete();`

**Delete Cache**

```
   $all_cache = $this->cache->cache_info();
     foreach ($all_cache as $cache_id => $cache) :              
            $this->cache->delete($cache_id);              
   endforeach;
```

Comment: my $cache_id is sesstion id . direct close  browser and open again may change sesstion id this time my file is unused ..that is my problem. am not save any data about file name in db. just it pick using sesstion id only